# Python-SQL - improve dataframe

Tags: python, sql

I have a database in SQL Server , I am importing the data to python - jupyter.

Now, I have a dataframe that look like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | & | ^ | a | 0.5 |
| **1** | & | ^ | b | 1.9 |
| **1** | & | ^ | c | 0.7 |
| **2** | @ | $ | a | 0.7 |
| **2** | @ | $ | b | 1.8 |
| **2** | @ | $ | d | 0.5 |

I want to get to a state that the dataframe is like:

| A | B | C | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | & | ^ | 0.5 | 1.9 | 0.7 | NaN |
| **2** | @ | $ | 0.7 | 1.8 | NaN | 0.5 |

mining I don't want duplicates data, columns A,B,C
and I want to transpose the data in column D,E that the data in column D
will become columns and their data will be from column E.

I don't mind to do it in the sql query or in python.

Comment: The transformation is unclear. Can you please provide further context around what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I added some context, please let me know if it's sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to direction of nodser.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['A','B','C'],
                    columns['D'],
                    values=['E],
                    aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Comment: If you don't need the summing functionality the unstack method is much much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

if `df` is the dataframe then this does it in python:

```
df.set_index(keys=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).unstack('D')
```

returns

```
         E               
D        a    b    c    d
A B C                    
1 & ^  0.5  1.9  0.7  NaN
2 @ $  0.7  1.8  NaN  0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

None dynamic SQL Version

```
select A      , B       , C 
     , a = max(case when D = 'a' then E end)
     , b = max(case when D = 'b' then E end)
     , c = max(case when D = 'c' then E end)
     , d = max(case when D = 'd' then E end)
   from dataframe
 group by A, B, C
```

But I suspect there needs to be a dynamic version that just knows single d value should be shown for related c value?